# Reading ESRI shapefiles from the InputStream in Java

Tags: java, spring, shapefile, geotools

I have a web application that is supposed to read a shapefile from a user's disk. I use a `MultipartFile` class (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) to upload it. As far as I understand, it is not possible to recover a file path from the `MultipartFile`. It causes a problem for me because I use the following code to interpret the shapefile content (I attach the constructor which is crucial):

```
    private ShapeFile(final File srcFile) {
    try {
        final Map<String, Serializable> params = ImmutableMap.of("url", srcFile.toURI().toURL());
        dataStore = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory().createDataStore(params);
        final String typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
        featureType = dataStore.getSchema(typeName);
        featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}
```

The shapefile needs the `File` in the constructor and the `File` is strictly associated with an absolute path of a file. Therefore, I cannot use the `MultipartFile` and create the `File` in a memory (i.e. not in a file system) based on that. What I can do, is getting the `InputStream` from the `MultipartFile`, `getInputStream()` or `getBytes()`.

Is there a way to modify the `Shapefile` constructor such that it accepts the `InputStream` or a table of bytes? I would like to avoid creating a temporary file.

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A [`MultiPartFile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) is a single file sent in multiple parts, a [ShapeFile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) is a collection of at least 3 and possibly up to 12 files that share a common basename and have various extensions, such as `.shp`, `.shx`, `.dbf`, `.prj` etc.

So it is impossible to construct a `ShapeFile` object from an `InputStream` or byte collection as the constructor needs to read from 3 files at once to tie the geometries (`.shp`) to the attributes (`.dbf`) using the index and other information scattered across the remaining files.

Comment: Hello, good point! What if I only need coordinates from a Shapefile?

Comment: It might be possible to hack something together to do that but there is nothing in the library to do that currently.  See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180515/geotools-create-shapefile-in-memory